# Extracting n characters from a test line

Tags: sed

How can I extract the 6 characters after Z in the following text line and put it into a file using grep, egrep, sed or awk?

B1_Site4_5aT4ZNHN691AQSB6B65_KYEC_SLT_2013-11-24-00-30_935985e7_100m_PASS1.tar

Answer (score 3):

```
file="B1_Site4_5aT4ZNHN691AQSB6B65_KYEC_SLT_2013-11-24-00-30_935985e7_100m_PASS1.tar"
```

with GNU `grep` when built with PCRE support (and with `zsh` or recent versions of `ksh93` or `bash` for `<<<`):

```
grep -oP '(?<=Z).{6}' <<< "$file" > file
```

with `ksh93`, `bash` or recent versions of `zsh`:

```
tmp=${file#*Z}              # remove chars up to the first Z
echo "${tmp:0:6}" > file
```

Just for fun, `awk`

```
awk -F Z '{print substr($2, 1, 6)}' <<< "$file"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
expr B1_Site4_5aT4ZNHN691AQSB6B65_KYEC_SLT_2013-11-24-00-30_935985e7_100m_PASS1.tar : '.*Z\(.\{6\}\)' > file
```

Or just with the shell

```
string=B1_Site4_5aT4ZNHN691AQSB6B65_KYEC_SLT_2013-11-24-00-30_935985e7_100m_PASS1.tar
printf '%.6s\n' "${string#*Z}" > file
```

(the first one will consider the last Z followed by 6 characters, the second one the first; behaviour will vary if their not ZXXXXXX in there).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>echo \
B1_Site4_5aT4ZNHN691AQSB6B65_KYEC_SLT_2013-11-24-00-30_935985e7_100m_PASS1.tar |
sed 's/.*Z\(.\{6\}\).*/\1/'
>>NHN691
```

Adding a `>file` will put it in a file.

Comment: As an Aging Dinosaur, I believe `sed` is the right choice. However, put the '|' at the end of the `echo` line, and you don't have to backslash the newline to get the pipeline continued.

Comment: @BruceEdiger, `sed` works on every line of its input, not the whole input, so somehow `expr` is more appropriate (`echo` has a few issues associated with it as well for arbitrary data).